# Where can I find the debug symbols Windows 10?

Tags: debug-symbols, windows-10, pdb-files

I'm looking for the symbol packages for Windows 10 RTM, but came up empty-handed. <s>Or rather, all I found was [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/hardware/gg463028#Download_windows) which contains symbols for old builds.</s> (the symbol packages were added now)

Is there a place to download the debug symbols for the 10240 build already or are they not yet available?

---

**Symbol packages** for Free *and* Checked builds of Windows 10 have arrived on MSDN for [subscribers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/subscriptions/securedownloads/#searchTerm=Windows%2010%20Symbols&ProductFamilyId=0&Languages=en&PageSize=10&PageIndex=0&FileId=0) and [non-subscribers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463028) alike. Unfortunately I have still [to come by any Checked builds for Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35940134/476371), though.

Comment: currently they are not available. I've already asked Microsoft and wait for a reply. Today I got some PDBs from the symbol server: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503/en-us

Comment: it looks like Microsoft currently uploads the PDBs. On a 32Bit Win10 I get a lot of them now via symchk.

Comment: Final package (MSI) can be found for x86 on MSDN now, but not for x64.

Comment: x64 symbols now available. Symbols also available for checked builds, but no checked builds, yet.

Comment: btw, grap them now. MS includes some very informational PDBs, not the normal public ones ;) Maybe they replace them soon.

Comment: @magicandre1981: well possible they simply put back in some of the stuff they left out in more recent versions. In the more distant past the symbols were more complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symbols are now also availably to the public without MSDN subscription:

> These packages contain the **full set of symbols required to debug
>   Windows 10, Windows 10 for Enterprise**, Windows Server Technical
>   Preview, Windows Datacenter Technical Preview, and Windows Hyper-V
>   Server Technical Preview, **released July 29, 2015**.

I see the retail and checked symbols for 32 and 64Bit.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463028